# webdriver test execution speed

Tags: performance, selenium, grid, webdriver

I run my tests basically on 3 browsers for now (IE9,FF,Chrome) and just made a research about time needed to run them !
My conclusion is that, more or less, a test in FF needs +-5 mins, in Chrome +-4 and in IE +-12 
Some tests need more and some other less but  IE32  always needs more than double of other browsers
I know it's normal IE   is the slowest one but do You think such big difference is normal ?

I use testNg + selenium grid on a remote machine Win7 64 bits.

Comment: So what is your question? Why is IE slower? Could you improve IE speed? Your question is vague.

Comment: Just would like to know if is it "normal" that IE needs 100% more than FF

Comment: And, of course, if is possible to imporve speed :-)

Comment: Yes, yes it is. No no it can't.

Comment: Needs more than 100% than FF of what? Memory? CPU Usage? Time it takes?  ....and anyway, what tests are you running? What code are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clear question here :( but...

In general you may be able to help your speed in IE by avoiding use of XPath locators - use lookups by id or css selectors or whatever in their place.

Comment: Try to give a longer answers in the future and with examples.